# Run shell script inside container and delete it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What's the proper way to run a lot of shell commands inside a Docker container?

Is it with a ton of `RUN` statements, or is it better to just throw everything into an `.sh` file and run it?

e.g., here's what I've got now:

```
FROM php:latest

COPY install-composer /tmp/
RUN /tmp/install-composer
RUN rm /tmp/install-composer
```

It seems kind of awkward to me that I have to copy my shell script into my container, run it, and then dispose of it manually.

Is there no way to just execute my shell script in the context of my container without copying it in?

Answer (score 2):

One common way is to run with a long `RUN` statement (this will produce fewer layers in image).

This is a long `RUN` I used:

`RUN \
    apk add --update $RUN_DEP                               && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*                                 && \
    mkdir -pv /run/nginx /config /data                      && \
    chown 65534:65534 /config /data                         && \
    ln -sv   /dev/stdout /var/log/php-fpm.log               && \
    ln -sv   /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log          && \
    ln -sv   /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log           && \
    ln -svfn /config     /usr/share/webapps/owncloud/config && \
    ln -svfn /data       /usr/share/webapps/owncloud/data   && \
    adduser nobody www-data`

Comment: Oy, that looks nasty to maintain. Why wouldn't they just add a convenience wrapper for this?